# Why do it this way? (use string Namevaluepairs and StringBuilder)

Tags: java, android, http, post

I recently saw a sample code that first creates NameValuePair object and populates it:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Param1", param1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Param2", param2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Param3", param3));
```

then passes that to another method to turn it to one string:

```
    private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

it seems to me that I could get the same result from doing this:

```
String query = "";
query += URLEncoder.encode("Param1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Param1, "UTF-8")
query += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Param2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Param2, "UTF-8")
query += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Param2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Param2, "UTF-8")
```

would my code work? if no, why? if yes, whats the advantages of doing it the other way?

I realize that former allows you to pass in any number of NVPs, but I just demonstrated that in the same number of lines it took to build the NVPs, I was able to build the whole POST string!

Comment: The first method could dynamically build the query based on any number of parameters, where as the latter is very limited and not very reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which uses `NameValuePair`s is more generic. `getQuery` is reusable, and is completely agnostic to the pairs passed to it.

If you leave design (and syntax) out of the equation, then your first alternative is equivalent.
The second alternative you suggested will **NOT** work, as it would escape the `=`s and the `&`s along with the parameters.

Comment: "he second alternative you suggested will NOT work, as it would escape the =s and the &s along with the parameters." <- thats the what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Since we're passing the params through URLencoder, is the pass through  BasicNameValuePair(), kinda redundant for formatting purposes. i.e. if I created a list of <string,string> used that instead of name value pairs, would it still work. I'm asking all of this for learning purposes.

Comment: Yes, `BasicNameValuePair` is nothing more than a utility class which holds two strings (+ implements relevant `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals`, but that's beside the point). So whether you're holding it as a list of `NameValuePair`s or your own container, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really about readability and reusability. The original code you saw is much more readable than a single inline string concatenation you suggest. Small, concise statements passed to a flexible method. Additionally, in the original, since the names and values are kept as separate fields, that name List could be reused for other things, if required, whereas your inline method is single purpose.

The two pieces of code should be pretty identical performance. When you look at what the Java compiler does to your string concatenation, it actually instantiates a StringBuilder itself to do the concatenation similar to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

from performance point of view does not matter as there is always small number of HTTP parameters.

Personally i like this way :

```
 new Uri.Builder()
.scheme("http")
.authority("foo.com")
.path("someservlet")
.appendQueryParameter("param1", foo)
.appendQueryParameter("param2", bar)
.build();
```

Comment: would this work for POST? also how does this fit into the rest of the HttpURLconnection flow. i.e. what do I do with the URI builder after this? thanks